# Three-dimensional pixel

Tags: graphics

If we have some two-dimensional function, for example $y = ix^2$, we can express that (or any) function with some kind of three-dimensional pixel ($t$ represents the pixel base). I know it sounds strange, but how a picture speaks louder than words, I posted a link where you can see what it looks like. https://www.desmos.com/3d/9df6a98697

If we look at the last two equations, we will notice that they are somewhat similar , that's because they are, and that's because $v$ plays $y$, and $z$ plays $x$ (and this works for any ratio of $x$ to $y$) My question is: How to convert three-dimensional pixels into two-dimensional ones.

Another question I have is whether there are similar examples of the mathematics I just presented or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.